# Register REST client in WSO2 API Manager issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

1.

I've been looking through the doc of wso2 apim. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide

And use the postman to send the request:
[image]
[image]

But I got 401 error response. As expected I should get the correct response payload like:

```
{
"callBackURL": "www.google.lk",
"jsonString":
"{
\"username\":\"admin\",
\"redirect_uris\":\"www.google.lk\",
\"tokenScope\":[Ljava.lang.String;@3a73796a,
\"client_name\":\"admin_rest_api_store\",
\"grant_types\":\"authorization_code password refresh_token iwa:ntlm
urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer client_credentialsimplicit\"
}",
"clientName": null,
"clientId": "HfEl1jJPdg5tbtrxhAwybN05QGoa",
"clientSecret": "l6c0aoLcWR3fwezHhc7XoGOht5Aa"
}
```

2.

I have used the same method to call another URL the response is 403.The URL is correct to enter the publisher.
How to solve it? Thank you.

Request Header
[image]
Request
[image]
Response Body
[image]
Response Cookies
[image]
Response Header
[image]

Publisher Log
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your Authorization header valid?
"YWRtaW46YWRtaW4= " is for default admin:admin credentials.

You should base64 encode your actual username:password and set the value as a header.

Comment: Yes, I solved the issue of response 401 .
But I have another issue as above mark 2, the URL response is 403.
How can I solve it?Thank you.

Comment: The mark 2 APIM is use Single Sign-On method to login.

Comment: It is the same url in both images. Is the attached image correct?

Comment: The URL IP is different and the 403 response is use Single Sign-On to login.